# I'm trying to do a Prime Number finder but cant see why it's not working

Tags: c#, list, numbers, primes

I'm trying to do a Prime Number finder but cant see why it's not working.
When i run the debug test nothing show in the console. Could someone check it and tell me what i do wrong?

```
  List<int> primes = new List<int>();
        primes.Add(2);
        primes.Add(3);
        int maxPrime = 11;                //The maximum found Primes
        int primeCount = primes.Count;     //Current Number of Primes
        int num = 4;                    //Current Number
        int x = 0;                 //
        int curPrime = primes[x];

        while (primeCount < maxPrime)
        {
            if (x != primeCount)
            {
                if (num % primes[x] == 0)
                {
                    num++;
                    x = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    x++; 
                }
            }

            else
            {
                primes.Add(num);
                primeCount=primes.Count;
                x = 0;
            }
        }
        primes.ForEach(i => Console.Write("{0}\t", i));
```

Comment: When you step through the code in the debugger, where *specifically* does the observed behavior differ from the expected behavior?  What are the runtime values when that happens?

Comment: there are so00000000 Many working examples on how to do this here is an even simpler example doing it with a single value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886540/prime-numbers-c-sharp

Comment: Increasing `primeCount` would help....

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop.

Since you never modify `primeCount` or `maxPrime`, this will *always* be true:

```
while (primeCount < maxPrime)
```

In order to end that loop, you need to modify one of those two values in such a way that the condition will evaluate to false.

(Note: There appear to also be other bugs/problems in the code aside from this.  For example, `num = num++;` doesn't do what you probably think it does.)